# regular oven conversion to support convection

Tags: electrical, heating, oven, fans

**Preface**: I thought about posting this on the [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) (Cooking) SE network but concluded that the engineering/architectural aspects of this topic and question justified placement here. I'm open to feedback on this.

**Summary, topic, and question**:
I've got what amounts to a "regular" electrical oven, and I want to enhance its functionality by adding some fan(s) to facilitate convection during baking, broiling, and especially roasting. I see a lot of online info about doing so by proxy through just modifying the time/temperature of a given recipe, which just doesn't work nearly as well IMHO.

What's a workable approach to achieving this objective?

Comment: Ovens get very hot.  Since they get hot any parts(fans,wires,controls) added to them must be made to handle the heat.  Placing a small desk fan in a oven is a bad idea.  Quite a few recipes can be adjusted.  I find turkey cooked at 350 tends to be dry, cooking it at 250 it falls off the bone and is juicy.  It is probably better to buy a convection oven than try modifying your plain oven, unless lucky enough that your oven has an addon for convection.  Online information might not be right or safe,  there are a lot of wrong/dangerous information online, double and triple check.

Comment: Surely the whole point of fans in ovens is to *counteract* convection, to equalise the temperature throughout the oven.

Comment: Do you have a fan to work at the max oven temperature?

Comment: @Chenmunka  Please let us know the right name.  To me an oven is a box that gets hot and cooks food, and I am happy.  I know there are other marketing buzz words to describe oven types, but to me it cooks food.  Do think you are right about convection being the wrong word we want.

Comment: @crip659:  My wife, a retired professional cook, simply refers to them as *Fan Ovens*.

Comment: @Chenmunka -- a [convection oven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection_oven) is an oven that has fans to circulate the air. The name may or may not be technically correct, but that's what it is.

Comment: Convection Oven, which pedants may consider as being a shortened form of **Forced** Convection Oven. Or even **Fan-Forced** Convection Oven. But down at the appliance shop, including the commercial appliance shop, you'll be looking at Convection Ovens.

Comment: As the Wikipedia article notes, this type of oven goes by several names around the world.  Probably an American vs. British (and more?) usage thing.  In the US they are marketed as Convection ovens.   Those that watch the Great British Baking Show on PBS, you'd note they refer to their oven settings as "<temp C> fan"

Comment: @Chenmunka  I think fan-ovens are more of an European term of use, but not a term used much in North America.

Comment: Fan/convection ovens have at least one set of elements behind the fan. I'm not sure using a regular oven with heat top & bottom then trying to blow that around is going to be equivalent, even if you do manage to find a fan [& cabling] that can stand 250°C without blinking.

Comment: The trick is to have the fan motor sit outside the oven and shaft penetrate the insulation envelope.  You won't find an electric motor that enjoys 600F, but you'll find shafts that do.

Comment: Keep in mind that a metal shaft will still be an amazing heat conductor, so the electric motor does have to have some resistance to high heat even if outside of the insulation envelope.

Comment: @Chenmunka They call them _convectionary_ ovens in my neighborhood.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A workable approach: Sell oven on craigslist (or whatever,) buy convection oven.

An approach that will invalidate your insurance coverage in the event of a fire related to the oven: Let's slap some fans on this oven I already have and ignore the whole "UL listing" thing that appliances go through, not to mention the expense of trying to home-engineer a fan arrangement that can take the heat, and the cost of my currently functional oven becoming junk due to unapproved modifications.

The latter approach might be suitable for "Junkyard Wars / Scrapheap Challenge" with TV money and nowhere near the inside of an actual home, but is otherwise, much like [Crazy Eddie's prices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Eddie), Insaaane.